# Django rest framework: custom headers are different in client than unittests

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest API and then, separately, a client that consume this API.

I pass a custom header using requests in the client:

```
r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers={'license': '12345'})
```

Then in API, in my custom permission, I get the header like:

```
app_license = request.META['HTTP_LICENSE']
```

I know django [rewrites the custom headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) for security reasons, so it works fine.

My problem is when I write the unittests in Django rest API:

```
response = self.client.get(self.url, params=params, headers={'license': '12345'})
```

Then it raise:

```
KeyError: 'HTTP_LICENSE'
```

But if I change the code like this, the test passes without problem but the consumer doesn't work:

```
request.META['headers']['license']
```

I can check if there is 'headers' key or not but I don't want to change the code only to pass the unittest, it must be some way to write a unittest that matches reality, right?

I tried to use:

```
from django.test import TestCase
```

And:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
```

Both with same result. There is any solution? Thank you!

Comment: If you pass in `HTTP_LICENSE` in the `self.client.get` call, does it perform as you like?

Comment: @sam If I pass HTTP_LICENSE as a header in self.client.get, it can be retrieve with: request.META['headers']['HTTP_LICENSE'], it is not the same behavior as with consumer request :(.

Comment: @sam I tried as you said: self.client.get(self.url, params=params, HTTP_LICENSE='12345') and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** — if you want something to show up in META, make it a `kwarg`. The `client.get` method is a different signature from `requests.get`.

---

This is because the kwargs of `self.client.get` map *directly* to HTTP attributes.

Take a [look at the source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/test/client/#RequestFactory). You'll notice the stack is:

1. `get`
2. `generic`
3. `request`
4. `_base_environ`

In that process, the `kwargs` are carried to `_base_environ` with very few alterations. They're then merged into a dictionary that includes all of the basic headers you'd expect:

```
    # This is a minimal valid WSGI environ dictionary, plus:
    # - HTTP_COOKIE: for cookie support,
    # - REMOTE_ADDR: often useful, see #8551.
    # See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#environ-variables
    environ = {
        'HTTP_COOKIE': self.cookies.output(header='', sep='; '),
        'PATH_INFO': '/',
        'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
        'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
        'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
        'SERVER_NAME': 'testserver',
        'SERVER_PORT': '80',
        'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
        'wsgi.version': (1, 0),
        'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
        'wsgi.input': FakePayload(b''),
        'wsgi.errors': self.errors,
        'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
        'wsgi.multithread': False,
        'wsgi.run_once': False,
    }
    environ.update(self.defaults)
    environ.update(request)
    return environ
```

The above is then passed into a `WSGIRequest` object in the `request` method. [That class then takes the provided `environ` dict and assigns it to the META property:](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c1c163b42717ed5e051098ebf0e2f5c77810f20e/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L66)

```
class WSGIRequest(HttpRequest):
    def __init__(self, environ):
        script_name = get_script_name(environ)
        # If PATH_INFO is empty (e.g. accessing the SCRIPT_NAME URL without a
        # trailing slash), operate as if '/' was requested.
        path_info = get_path_info(environ) or '/'

        ##############################
        ##                          ##
        ## This is the line you're  ##
        ##       looking for.       ##
        ##                          ##
        ##############################
        self.environ = environ
        self.path_info = path_info
```